# Why isn't this simple IF statement not working?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I can't get this script to work for nothing. I tried many different ways to make this work but it's not working.

```
<?php 
if (!empty ($image->alttext )) : ?>
<div class="thumbtitle"><?php echo $image->alttext ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

It always shows true that there is alttext when there isn't sometimes.

Comment: what's the value of $image->alttext?

Comment: Did you intend to use a double negative in your title? If it isn't not working, then do you mean it's working??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is vague but try the following

```
<?php 
if (strlen(trim($image->alttext)) > 0) : ?>
    <div class="thumbtitle"><?php echo $image->alttext ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As said your string is probably not empty but with whitespaces.
use var_dump() or strlen() to find out. With trim you remove the whitespaces.

Comment: You might want to explain what is wrong with the original code, since that is the question.

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm! It was in the back of my mind that I might have to trim it, but not that advanced in php to write the code.

Answer (score 2):

The value in `$image->alttext` is probably not blank, maybe there are white spaces in it.
You can trim it first before testing.

```
$imgText = trim($image->alttext);
if (!empty ($imgText)) : ?>
<div class="thumbtitle"><?php echo $image->alttext ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Note**: use var_dump($image->alttext) to see that it has the value you are expecting.